# Merge 2 Pandas DataFrame, Take One Record Over Another if Index Matches

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two Pandas DataFrames, but anywhere an index matches I only want to merge in the row from a specific `df`.

So if I have

```
df1
             A  B
type   model
apple  v1    10 xyz
orange v2    11 pqs

df2
             A  B
type   model
apple  v3    11 xyz
grape  v4    12 def
```

I would get

```
df3 
             A  B
type   model
apple  v1    10 xyz
orange v2    11 pqs
grape  v4    12 def
```

Because `df1.ix['apple']` takes precedence over `df2.ix['apple']`, and `orange` and `grape` are unique.

I have been trying to make some index comparison work, but `df2.drop(df1.index[[0]])` is just removing the entire contents of `df2`.

Both data frames are multi-indexed with a similar structure, created by:

`pd.read_csv(..., index_col=[3, 1])`

Which results in an index like this:

```
MultiIndex(
  levels=[[u'apple', u'orange', u'grape', ...], [u'v1', u'v2', u'v3', ... ]],
  labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...]],
  names=[u'type', u'model']
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [`DataFrame.combine_first()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) is for:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 11], 'B': ['xyz', 'pqs']}, index=['apple', 'orange'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [11, 12], 'B': ['xyz', 'def']}, index=['apple', 'grape'])

df3 = df1.combine_first(df2)
```

yields

```
df3
           A    B
apple   10.0  xyz
grape   12.0  def
orange  11.0  pqs
```

---

EDIT: The question was substantially modified after I posted the answer above — adding the `model` level to the index, effectively turning it into a MultiIndex.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the df1 in the question
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'model': ['v1', 'v2'], 'A': [10, 11], 'B': ['xyz', 'pqs']},
                   index=['apple', 'orange'])
df1.index.name = 'type'
df1.set_index('model', append=True, inplace=True)

# Create the df2 in the question
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'model': ['v3', 'v4'], 'A': [11, 12], 'B': ['xyz', 'def']},
                   index=['apple', 'grape'])
df2.index.name = 'type'
df2.set_index('model', append=True, inplace=True)

# Solution: remove the `model` from the index and apply the above
#     technique. Restore it to the index at the end if you want.
df1.reset_index(level=1, inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(level=1, inplace=True)
df3 = df1.combine_first(df2).set_index('model', append=True)
```

Result:

```
df3
                 A    B
type   model           
apple  v1     10.0  xyz
grape  v4     12.0  def
orange v2     11.0  pqs
```

Comment: I updated my question, but I have a multi-index. When I am using combine_first, it is just merging the index together, so I would end up with both apples - is it possible to use `.combine_first` with `.groupby(level=0)`?

Comment: @getglad: I suggest you post this as a new question, with more information and a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this if you want to preserve NaN's in the `df1`'s cells or if you have a multiindex, for which you would receive: `NotImplementedError: merging with both multi-indexes is not implemented` when using `combine_first()`:

```
In [53]: df1
Out[53]:
              A    B
ind1 ind2
foo  apple   10  NaN
bar  orange  11  pqs
baz  grape   12  def

In [54]: df2
Out[54]:
             A    B
ind1 ind2
foo  apple  11  xyz
baz  grape  12  def

In [55]: pd.concat([df1, df2.ix[df2.index.difference(df1.index)]])
Out[55]:
              A    B
ind1 ind2
foo  apple   10  NaN
bar  orange  11  pqs
baz  grape   12  def
```

**OLD answer:**

for example (pay attention at `apple` row in `df1`):

```
In [33]: df1
Out[33]:
         A    B
apple   10  NaN
orange  11  pqs
grape   12  def

In [34]: df2
Out[34]:
        A    B
apple  11  xyz
grape  12  def

In [35]: df1.combine_first(df2)
Out[35]:
         A    B
apple   10  xyz
grape   12  def
orange  11  pqs

In [36]: pd.concat([df1, df2.ix[df2.index.difference(df1.index)]])
Out[36]:
         A    B
apple   10  NaN
orange  11  pqs
grape   12  def
```

Otherwise the solution from @Alberto Garcia-Raboso (for normal indices) is definitely better and faster. It might also work in future pandas versions...

Comment: just curious - what was wrong with your first answer `.groupby(level=0).first()`?

Comment: @getglad, it wouldn't work correctly if in resulting DF we would have first row from `df2` and then from `df1` with the same index...